# Cómo iniciar Formulario y WebApi en una solución C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Tengo una solución en C# con varios proyectos (incluida una web api).

- Desde el 'program' de inicio, quiero lanzar el form principal ('form1') y cargar tb la web api, como sigue:

  ```
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;


  namespace Jardineria
  {
    static class Program
    {
      [STAThread]
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Application.Run(new Form1());
      }

      public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
              });
    }
  }
  ```
- El problema es que me da error en 'IHostBuilder', con el '.ConfigureWebHostDefaults', diciendo que no contiene definición ni método accesible.
  En teoría, tengo que utilizar:
  'using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;'
  Pero me dice que ASPNetCore no existe en el espacio de nombres de Microsoft.
- Una posible solución que no me ha funcionado es pasar de Aplication de Consola a aplicación Web, sustituyendo ' `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk` ' en el .csproj de la siguiente forma:

  ```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
      <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    </PropertyGroup>
  ```
- El problema es que en mi .csproj no se qué debería modificar. Mi .csproj es:

  ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props')" />
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{82D4B739-1872-4D46-B5C7-E133E7167750}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Jardineria</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Jardineria</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.5.0.0\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0\lib\net45\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.1\lib\net463\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.5.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Json.5.0.0\lib\net461\System.Text.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CEntidades\CEntidades.csproj">
      <Project>{3b551afc-7838-4ca7-8e94-767c42fc89a1}</Project>
      <Name>CEntidades</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CNegocio\CNegocio.csproj">
      <Project>{f974d4d5-5f3a-4dd8-8491-6e095bd455e1}</Project>
      <Name>CNegocio</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 %28x86 y x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>Este proyecto hace referencia a los paquetes NuGet que faltan en este equipo. Use la restauración de paquetes NuGet para descargarlos. Para obtener más información, consulte http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. El archivo que falta es {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.5.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.targets')" />
  ```

Algún consejo que me pueda ayudar a solucionar el problema??

Gracias de antemano..

Comment: Tengo algunas preguntas, pero la principal es: Si un Api generalmente es para el lado  del servidor y win form está orientado al cliente ¿Por qué quieres mezclarlos en un solo proyecto?. Otra pregunta: ¿No te sirve ejecutar cada una por separado? y la otra ¿utilizas Visual Studio? y en caso afirmativo ¿cual versión?.

Comment: si tambien tengo algunas preguntas como @PabloGutiérrez, acaso quieres conectarte desde el winform al api o algo asi?? si es el caso creo que deberías tener un proyecto para el api y otro para el winform

Comment: Hola Pablo y Carlos. Si efectivamente, necesito conectarme para realizar una prueba. Es decir, Me he creado una BBDD MySql con HEIDISql, y le estoy pasando los datos vía web api, como si estuviese en otra web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO.
He tenido que instalar el paquete "Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" con NuGet.

Gracias.